# Is there any way to allow multithreading on a program with a loop like this one?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Is there any way to allow multithreading on a program with a loop like this one?

`int a=100000,b=50,c;while(a){c=b*a+c;a--;}`

Windows 7/Code::Blocks IDE with the default mingw c++ compiler/Dual-core 4 threaded i5 cpu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a programming issue per se.

Your CPU has either four cores, or two cores with hyperthreading.  The program is using 100% of 1 core, which is reported as 25% usage in the Windows task manager.

You won't be able to 'increase your CPU usage' without threading.

(As an aside, the reason you see it as 'distributed between the four threads' is because the operating system is, if you like, changing its mind about which core it wants to run your program on.  Such issues of scheduling can't be changed (and won't have a noticable impact on) individual programs.)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, it fully answers my question, I really didn't know that threads could be considered as cores.

Comment: Threads are not considered cores, but a thread can only run on one core at a time so if you want to use more than one core you are required to use more than one thread.  Using multiple threads is fundamentally hard though; you need to be careful or else your program will have unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @DavidGrayson - I thought Windows didn't make a distinction between real and hyperthreaded 'cores'?  I'm more of a Unix guy, though, so I could be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: Well, there is one way to 'increase CPU usage' without threading -- just run four instances of your program at the same time.

Comment: You could also use [OpenMP's parallel for-loops](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#LoopDirectiveFor) if it's appropriate for the given problem.

Comment: @MikaelPersson That's the point, there's no way to speed up a program like the one below? Is there any way to use parallel processing on a program like this? int a=100,b=50,c;while(a){c=c+b*a;a--;}
(consider an important number of loops, some milions or so)